# Usage of its or their with the group entity

Tags: grammar

I am confused between below sentences. I am not sure which one is grammatically correct. Online grammar checking tools such as "grammarly" are not showing any issue with all below sentences.

1 - Nowadays, the urban population is facing many hurdles in their daily lives.

2 - Nowadays, the urban population is facing many hurdles in its daily life.

3 - Nowadays, the urban population are facing many hurdles in their daily lives.

4 - Nowadays, the urban population are facing many hurdles in its daily life.

Comment: This question had been discussed on this site more than once.  Have you tried using the search window of this site?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, I am still having a lot of confusion here. If you see my question, then they are many variations in sentences in which I have a question.

Comment: Tuffy was not only correct but rather reserved, there, Gaurav Dave.

That Question has been not only discussed more than once, but done to death both here and on other sites such as english Language Lerners, which is where it really belongs.

Please ask yourself whether "the urban population" is a singular thing, or a plural group and if in doubt, please ask ELL.

Comment: I've got to say that I think, if you're not prepared to reformulate, only (3) (and yes, that demands notional agreement) is unoutlandish here.

Answer (score 1):

You are neglecting to consider humanity's base instinct to anthropomorphize inanimate objects.

> Nowadays, the urban population is facing many hurdles in **its** daily life.

When you use *its* you are consciously or unconsciously distancing yourself from the subject in that sentence.

> Nowadays, the urban population is facing many hurdles in **their** daily lives.

The *their* attempts an association at a 'collective whole' (possibly *embracing* it) which may or may not include yourself but certainly one you recognize.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these sentences are all grammatically well formed. "Urban population" is a collective noun, and therefore can be either singular or plural. Using it as a singular noun will emphasize the characteristics of the group as a whole. Using it as a plural noun will emphasize the characteristics of the individuals in the group.

Given the context, which is the daily lives of people living in cities, I would say that Nos. 1 and 3 make the most sense. In other words, each member of the urban population has an individual daily life. Of course, in an abstract sense, all the things that happen to everyone in the urban population in the course of the day form a collective daily life, so I would be reluctant to say that Nos. 2 and 4 are wrong, because they are not.

Consider, however, that if you say that the urban population is shrinking, it would most likely be understood to mean that there are fewer people living in the city than ever before. On the other hand, if you say that the urban population are shrinking, someone could take it to mean that people living in the city are not as tall as they once were.

Comment: I would say 4 is wrong, as it uses _urban population_ in the plural, but then uses a singular pronoun to refer to them. It sounds fine the other way round (1), though.

Comment: I wouldn't say that either 1 or 4 "sound" fine. If I were editing a paper and came across any of these, I would make significant changes. But I do consider them all grammatically well formed, since I don't consider grammar to be prescriptive.